# Are any of Euclid's 5 postulates false in Minkowski spacetime?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, distance

I often hear that Minkowski spacetime is non-euclidean. Euclidean geometry is characterized by Euclid's five postulates being true. Which of those postulates are untrue in Minkowski spacetime (if any), and what physical consequences do we observe from them?

Comment: The question is quite meaningless until you specify how you're going to interpret words like "point", "line" and "angle" in Minkowski spacetime.  Is the postulate "every grib contains a grob" true in Minkowski spacetime?  Yes or no, depending entirely on how you interpret the words "grib" and "grob".

Comment: @WillO - "The question is quite meaningless ..." - and yet Jerry Schirmer was able to provide an answer. Try to be nicer with your comments.

Comment: @peter4075:  jerry was able to provide an answer contingent on a particular interpretation for the word "angle".  With a different (and equally reasonable) choice the answer would be different.

Comment: @WillO: but that's what a postulate is, a choice for what you mean by terms.

Comment: interesting. isn't minkowski spacetime already endowed with a metric (minkowski metric) and then the notion of distance, angle, etc ... naturally follow ? i'm honestly asking, not contradicting what either of you have said.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer :  No; a postulate (in general) contains terms that are undefined.  A **model** (or **interpretation**) assigns meanings to those terms.  The same postulate can become true in one interpretation and false in another.  In this case, the interpretation wasn't specified, so we can't assign a truth value.  Of course you went ahead and specified an interpretation, but the point is that the question was not answerable until **somebody** did that, and that we cannot know whether your interpretation coincides with the OP's intent.

Comment: @marjimbel : The answer to your last comment is, I think, a matter of social convention.  There is more than one way to intepret the word "angle" in minkowski spacetime.  What you are saying, I think, is that one of those interpretations is more natural than the others, so  that an ordinary reader will automatically adopt that interpretation, making it unnecessary for you to supply it.  Whether that's true depends on who your readers are and what their habits are.  To me, it seems like there's more than one natural interpretation.  To others, it might seem there's only one....(CONTINUED)

Comment: (CONTINUED)....And I have no idea how representative I or those others are of the population that's reading this question.  So in my opinion, it would have been better to specify what you meant.

Comment: i was inplicitly thinking of "angle" as defined by the inner product of two vectors using minkowski metric. what other definitions of 'angle' are you thinking of ? just curious.

Answer (score 11):

The Pythagorean distance formula doesn't hold for arbitrary shapes, thanks to the negative sign in the metric.  It's also pretty easy to say that boosts obey hyperbolic angle addition rules rather than circular ones.  Since the postulate about the congruency of right angles is needed to prove the Pythagorean distance relation, and angle addition rules for timelike intervals are different than those for spacelike intervals, one would conclude that the "all right angles are congruent" postulate doesn't hold-- the "right angle" between two null directions is different than that between two spacelike directions.

Comment: interesting. do you have a way to show intuitively that angle addition rules are different for timelike vs spacelike intervals, or a reference ? also, i guess minkowski space itself isn't hyperbolic. the "space of boosts" is hyperbolic in the sense that an event gets mapped to another event within a hyperboloid. if minkowski was hyprbolic, then it would have negative curvature, no? it is in fact flat, in the sense of zero riemman curvature tensor.

Comment: @marjimbel ... concerning the addition angle rules, look at the Yaglom reference in my answer. I think my answer is a first step in that direction. Eventually, one would use the cross-ratio to define the angle in that geometry.

Comment: cool. i will. just to summarize so far. we saying that both postulates 1 (existence of line segments) and 4 (congruent right angles) fail in Minkowski, but not the parallel postulate ?

Comment: I don't buy this answer. It's true that the right angle postulate is needed to prove the Pythagorean formula, but it's not the only thing needed to prove it. So we can't necessarily conclude from the failure of Pythagoras that the right angle postulate was the initial failure point.

Comment: Note that under the interpretation given in @robphy's answer (where we only consider timelike geodesics to be lines), the right angle postulate is vacuously true, as there are no right angles.

Comment: Is the fourth postulate fundamentally about right-angles? Or is it really about something else (homogeneity and isotropy) which we are here characterizing with right-angles?

Comment: @robphy: Euclid phrases it in terms of right angles, but I'm sure it's equivalent to timelike into spacelike anisotropy here.

Answer (score 4):

> Euclidean geometry is characterized by Euclid's five postulates being true

This is true, but what characterizes non-Euclidean geometry are deviations from the parallel postulate, specifically.

Minkowski space with the *flat* Minkowski metric has submanifolds that have non-Euclidean geometry ([hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model) geometry). This means that Euclid's [parallel postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate) is violated: basically, if the parallel postulate does hold for a given geometry, then the sum of the angles of a triangle is $\pi$ radians since the separation between parallel lines is constant. The geometry is non-Euclidean when the sum of the angles of a triangle is greater than (spherical) or less than (hyperbolic) $\pi$ radians, since the separation between parallel lines increases or decreases, respectively.

EDIT: After thoughtful feedback in the comments, I tried to make it clear that the fifth postulate is violated on the submanifolds of a Lorentzian manifold, whereas the entire Minkowski spacetime is indeed flat (and affine meaning Euclid/Playfair parallelism holds on the Lorentz manifold).

Comment: the hyperbolic properties refer to the geometry of the "space of boosts", no ? if minkowski spacetime itself had a hyperbolic geometry then it would have negative curvature, which it doesn't since it is a "flat space" in the sense of zero riemman curvature tensor. what am i missing ?

Comment: It truly depends on what we mean by "geometry." See here for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Geometry

Comment: So I think we agree that the kinematic space of a minkowski spacetime is hyperbolic. The thing is, "flatness" is a property of the metric chosen, and we use the flat minkowski metric in my answer. Apologies for not specifying that before.

Comment: More to your question: Minkowski space is not Reimannian, but it has submanifolds that are which have hyperbolic geometry (negative curvature), while the whole Minkowski manifold is flat, in the sense you mean, when endowed with the flat Minkowski metric (also called the Lorentz metric).

Comment: so you mean that Minkowski space is just a vector space and has no "geometry" until we endow it with a specific metric, in this case the "Minkowski metric" ? once we have decided on the metric, though, i agree that the hyperbolic geometry only applies to the submanifold and not to the space itself. so that when you say that "Euclid's parallel postulate is violated" you mean only within that submanifold, but not on minkowski space itself. similar to how the surface of a sphere embedded in euclidean space is non-euclidean ?

Comment: also, then, would you agree with the other comments that on minkowski space (with minkowski metric) the postulates violated are actually the first and third, and that those are connected to the causal structure of the theory ?

Comment: The hyperbolic aspect of Minkowski space involves the way angles are measured, using the arc of a unit hyperbola. In Euclidean geometry, angles are measured using the arc of a unit circle. In both cases, no aspect of the Parallel Postulate is involved here. Both (and also the Galilean spacetime) are so-called "affine geometries" where the Parallel Postulate holds. This is also discussed in the Yaglom reference in my answer.

Comment: Use the Playfair formulation of the Parallel postulate ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair%27s_axiom ) to remove Euclidean-notions like angle sums of 180-degrees. In the end, what is more likely important are "angle defects" and the Gauss-Bonnet theorem. But, if you hold on to Euclidean-centric concepts, then you'll more easliy find "failure" in these neighboring geometries.

Comment: @marjimbel indeed, I mean that the fifth postulate is violated within that submanifold, which determines the negative curvature. All three postulates are violated in Minkowski space: I totally agree that the violation of the first and third postulates result in the unique causal structure of 4D Minkowski spacetime, but I maintain that it is the violation of Euclid's parallel postulate that causes the kinematics to be hyperbolic (by definition of course).

Comment: @robphy minkowski spacetime's geometry, Lorentz Geometry, is indeed affine, but Euclidean space and Minkowski spacetime have different symmetry groups since they have different metrics. I suppose I should say in my answer, to be more clear, instead that "Minkowski space with the flat Minkowski metric has submanifolds that have non-Euclidean geometry."

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of "submanifolds that have non-euclidean geometry". Euclidean geometry has submanifolds with non-euclidean geometry.

Comment: Clearly the parallel postulate is violated in the submanifolds. And indeed, we can embed, for instance, the non-Euclidean 2-sphere into Euclidean 3 space, even though Euclidean 3 space is flat and obeys the parallel postulate. I just don't want to be misleading, so I'm trying to be specific: Minkowski space is Euclidean (which is obvious if you allow the time coordinate to be imaginary), but it has non-Euclidean submanifolds that result in hyperbolic kinematics, which relates to the OP's question about Euclid's postulates.

Comment: I don't understand why it would be of interest that there are submanifolds that are non-flat. Euclidean space also has submanifolds (e.g., the sphere) that are non-flat.

Comment: The kinematical space (which are specific submanifolds) of minkowski relativity is non-euclidean - an example of the parallel postulate being violated.

Comment: i think we are on the same page about the submanifold stuff, and thank you for clarifying. just picking up on the comment that "minkowski space is euclidean". can you elaborate ? if i understand euclidean as meaning that none of 5 postulates are violated (is this a correct?) then i guess your statement would contradict what other's have said about the first or third postulate not being true in minkowski space ?

Answer (score 3):

Minkowski spacetime violates Euclid's First Postulate,
when expressed in a form like the Playfair postulate.
Physically, this violation tells us something about the Causal Structure in spacetime.

The first postulate can be expressed like the "dual" version of the fifth postulate:
"Given a point, and a line not through that point, there exists no point on that line which cannot be joined (by an “ordinary” line) to the given point."

So, for special relativity, I write it like:
"Given an event, and a worldline not experiencing that event, there exists infinitely many events on that worldline which are not “timelike-related” to the given event."

For Galilean relativity,
"Given an event, and a worldline not experiencing that event, there exists one event on that worldline which is not “timelike-related” to the given event."

(I think the Parallel Postulate (suitably expressed, e.g. Playfair) is okay for Galilean and Minkowski spacetimes. I think it's what allows us to draw parallel lines... like the ends of a meterstick on a spacetime diagram.)

update:
This viewpoint is what I physically interpreted from
 I.M. Yaglom's "A simple non-Euclidean geometry and its physical basis : an elementary account of Galilean geometry and the Galilean principle of relativity"
 https://archive.org/details/ASimpleNon-euclideanGeometryAndItsPhysicalBasis/page/n237 .
See Figures 188a-c on page 220, which I inserted below.
[image: robphy-interprets-FirstPostulate-Yaglom-p220]

> (From Yaglom, p220)
>  In accordance with the requirement of congruence of any two lines in 
>   the plane, it is natural to define the "Minkowskian plane" as the points of 
>   the (ordinary) plane and the lines of one kind—say, the first. In this 
>   connection we note that in Euclidean geometry every point on a line a can 
>   be joined by a line to a point A not on a (Fig. 188a); in Galilean geometry, 
>   each line a contains a unique point, "parallel" to A, which cannot be 
>   joined by an (ordinary) line to A (Fig. 188b); in Minkowskian geometry, 
>   there are infinitely many points on a line a of the first kind which cannot 
>   be joined to A by means of lines of the first kind (Fig. 188c). On the other 
>   hand, all three geometries share the property that through any point A not 
>   on a there passes a unique line not intersecting a (a unique line parallel to 
>   a).

Comment: this is very interesting and i had never heard of an example of a geometry that deviates from euclid's in the first postulate instead of the parallel postulate. i think the parallel postulate being violated leads to "curved" spaces, such as hyperbolic. however, minkowski is "flat". i struggle to reconcile the fact that Minkowski is flat with the fact that it is a non-euclidean geometry, and that is what lies behind my initial question

Comment: I agree with your characterization. Minkowski spacetime is a flat (zero-curvature) space. It is a Cayley-Klein geometry. I will update my answer with a reference.

Comment: You're implicitly defining "lines" to be timelike geodesics.  This is an interesting choice, and it might be justifiable, but in some ways it would be more natural to consider all geodesics (timelike, null, or spacelike) as the "lines" in spacetime.

Comment: This is Yaglom's characterization, which is very appealing. I can unify much of Euclidean, Minkowski, and Galilean by working on the analogies between timelike-geodesics. (The deSitter spacetimes can be included with more work.... on my to-do list.) The other types (spacelike and null) are handled specially, as needed.

Comment: Note that if you adopt @MichaelSeifert's choice, the axiom that gets violated is one Euclid considered so obvious that he didn't even state it explicitly, namely [Hilbert's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms) first axiom of congruence (roughly, if $\overline{AB}$ is a line segment, and $\gamma$ a ray with vertex $C$, there is some $D$ on $\gamma$ such that $\overline{AB}$ is congruent to $\overline{CD}$).

Comment: Along these lines, I like to point out that the position-vs-time graph in PHY 101 has a non-Euclidean spacetime geometry,.. the Galilean geometry, where lengths of worldlines are measured by "wristwatches". We have no problem with the Parallel postulate here.

Comment: The discussion here illustrates the point I'm trying to make in my comments on the main question.  Whether Euclid's first postulate is true in Minkowski spacetime depends entirely on what meanings you choose to assign to the words "line" and "point".  This answer makes one possible assignment of meanings.  There are alternatives, as pointed out by @MichaelSeifert .  Until you specify the interpretation, the question by itself is meaningless.

Comment: Please help me out here. Euclid's first axiom is that a (unique) straight line segment can be drawn joining any two points. That is lso true for events in Minkowski space. Are you not modifying Euclid's first axiom by distinguishing straight lines by whether they have a negative, zero, or positive metrical length, and then rejecting some of these? Why does that not make it a different axiom than Euclid's?

Comment: @lsfinn Via projective geometry, Yaglom reinterprets the first postulate as dual to the Playfair's version of the parallel postulate (5th). In that context, "the weakening the existence and uniqueness of a parallel line (to allow zero or an infinity) through a distant point in the 5th" is dual to "the weakening the nonexistence of inaccessible points (to allow exactly one or an infinity) by a line with positive-square-norm tangent [timelike] in the 1st". As the weakening of the 5th suggests elliptic and hyperbolic geometry, the weakening of the 1st suggests Galilean and Minkowski spacetime.

Answer (score 1):

This is from Schutz's *A First Course in General Relativity* (second edition, page 117):[image]